# tomcat filter redirected jsp page does not show anything

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, servlets

Basically, I have a `login.jsp` page and a filter that checks if a session is valid or not. If the session is valid then continue, if not it will redirect to `login.jsp`.

The filter performs the redirection. However, after being redirected to `login.jsp`, nothing is shown on webpage. I am sure it's a problem with the filter, because after removing the filter from `web.xml`, the `login.jsp` displays webpage.

The filter is very simple and I got it from here. I don't know where the problem is in this case. Any suggestions?

```
  if(request.getRequestURI().compareToIgnoreCase("/login.jsp")!=0)
   {
      if (session != null) 
        {
          if(!session.isNew()) 
            {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        } 
      else 
       {
          System.out.println("Directed");
          response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp"); 
      }
  }
    else 
   {
      System.out.println("not directed");
  }
```

Comment: The login.jsp is very simple too, it just contains a form that takes username and password

Comment: just noticed that after redirection, all code within <body></body> is missing is login.jsp

Comment: Also please format code correctly for easier reading. :)

Comment: @ikel are you aware that the Web Container itself is capable of exactly this functionality - checking if user is authenticated and redirecting to login page if he's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to continue the filter chain for URI's matching the `login.jsp` string. Now all you do is print.

Like this:

```
{
    System.out.println("not directed");
    chain.doFilter(req,res);
}
```

In the outer else.

Comment: so i have to create a doChian method? sorry im new to server side stuff :)

Comment: let me try and get back to you soon